# Checking that polynomials over a field is a vector space

Tags: polynomials, vector-spaces

Using Axler's notation, let $\mathcal{P}(F)$ denote the set of all polynomials with coefficients in $F$. I'm trying to show that $\mathcal{P}(F)$ is a vector space over $F$. Axler states that we should use the "standard definition of addition and scalar multiplication." I have an intuitive sense of what this is, but I don't know how to formalize the idea of an adding $n$-degree polynomial to an $m$-degree polynomial where $n < m$. I could attempt to "embed" the $n$-degree polynomial in the set of $m$-degree polynomials by setting $a_i = 0$ for all $n < i \leq m$, but that seems to me like a completely different vector space. Another option is to just "carry over" the coefficients for all monomials $x^i$ where $n < i \leq m$ since there isn't anything to add to them / alter them, but that isn't very formal.

Is there a good way to write this?

Comment: If $m>n$ then an n-degree polynomial is an m-degree polynomial with coefficients of 0 for all terms of degree greater than $n$.

Comment: The definitions I know of "polynomials with coefficients in $F$" already include the fact that $\mathcal P(F)$ is a vector space over $F$ with additional structure. What's yours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Axler states that we should use the "standard definition of addition and scalar multiplication." I have an intuitive sense of what this is, but I don't know how to formalize the idea of an adding $n$-degree polynomial to an $m$-degree polynomial where $n < m$.

If $\mathcal{P}(F)$ represents ***all*** polynomials, it should be taken as including them all. Even if $\deg(p) = n, \deg(q) = m \ne n$, both $p,q$ lie in $\mathcal{P}(F)$.

Moreover, "padding out" the polynomial of lesser degree with terms with zero as the coefficient will still result in a polynomial in the space; you are simply changing how you write the polynomial, but it is nonetheless equivalent. After all, there should be no disagreement that
$$
x^2 + x + 1 \equiv 0x^4 + 0x^3 + x^2 + x + 1
$$
as polynomials. Certainly any equivalent representation of the same polynomial should live in the space.

---

If you wish to insist upon a formal definition, you can define the polynomial space (at least, in an isomorphic sense) as infinite vectors

$$p := (a_0,a_1,a_2,a_3,\cdots) \text{ analogous to the sum } a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + \cdots$$

where, for some $N_p \in \mathbb{N}$, we have $a_n = 0$ for all $n \ge N_p$. Then you can define the addition in the same way you would for tuples or sequences: pointwise. (And with no hemming-and-hawing about extra zeroes, because they're there from the start, though this notation loses its value when we move to multiplication.)

Clunkier, but closer to our intuition of a polynomial, we can define

$$\sum_{n=0}^N a_n x^n + \sum_{n=0}^M b_n x^n := \sum_{n=0}^{\max\{N,M\}} c_n x^n$$

where

$$c_n := \begin{cases}
a_n + b_n, & 1 \le n \le \min \{N,M\} \\
a_n, & \min \{N,M\} < n \le \max\{N,M\} \text{ and } N \ge M \\
b_n, & \min \{N,M\} < n \le \max\{N,M\} \text{ and } M \ge N \\
\end{cases}$$

This matches up entirely with our definition of polynomial addition since, after all, there is no stipulation that we can't have leading zeroes (unless we care about degree, which we do not here).